# Git Deployment from Web Hooks, How can i change the user file is executed as

Tags: php, git, magento, deployment

I am trying to set up automatic deployment for a Magento store. I have put together some basic scripts that pull master branch directly to my production web folder using a web hook which works great however am slightly worried about permissions.

To have this work i had to make the whole web folder apache:apache for owenership so that the web hook when running php as the apache user could do the pull request.

I would rather however have the permissions set slightly differently so a user admin:apache and have the deploy script run as admin user for better security.

Is there a way to have a php file that is triggered by a web hook run as another user. I read that chmod u+s would run the file as the owner of that file however this does not seem to be working. What are my best options for this or shall i just leave the web user as completely owning the whole folder?

I've read that this can be done via phpFPM or maybe SuPHP however unsure which way to go or what others generally do in this situation.

**My Solution**

I'm thinking i may have the deploy script just set a flag, a needs updating flag in a file. Then to run as whichever user i can set a cron for the user i want it to run as to check this flag file for if updates are required and then if so then run my scripts. This may be a long way around but was the best i could think of with my limited knowlesdge here.

Comment: First of all: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: I use both but this project is Magento 2.